# Concourse: How to use image's entrypoint for the Task?

Tags: concourse, concourse-task

I have an image with a fairly complicated entry point (basically java command). It's an OCI image with no shell. I am defining a concourse task, but if you see here
https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html#schema.task.run looks like run is compulsory.

I don’t want to specify to the concourse how to run it, the entry point is set already in the image. Is there an option that makes concourse to run the image entry-point?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create a script with your entrypoint command and call it.

```
FROM alpine:3.13
COPY script-with-entrypoint-command /bin/entrypoint
```

And then call it in your task

```yaml
- name: my-task
  config:
    run: entrypoint
```